# Help in finding a contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $0 < |\alpha| < 1$. Find $\displaystyle{\int_{\gamma}\frac{\mathrm{Re}(z)}{z-\alpha}dz}$

in terms of $\alpha$, where $\gamma$ is the circle $|z| = 1$ oriented in the counterclockwise
direction.

I tried to express $\mathrm{Re}(z)$ as $\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$. Then how should I proceed on? Any idea/suggestion is welcomed!:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that when $|z|=1$, $\bar{z}=\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Ok! I got it! thanks!

Comment: @Alan: You are welcome!